# When drawing FSM automata, tikz seems to eat the arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I have the following automata, and notice that some of the arrows have been eaten by Tikz for some reason. I've drawn where I expected to see arrows in red (roughly).

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state, initial] (s1) {$s_1$};
\node[state, right=2cm of s1] (s2) {$s_2$};
\node[state, accepting, right=2cm of s2] (s3) {$s_3$};

\draw   (s1) edge[loop above] node{0} (s1)
        (s1) edge[above] node{1} (s2)
        (s2) edge[loop above] node{1} (s2)
        (s2) edge[above] node{0} (s3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I also imported following libraries:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
```

I based my code off the example on Page 4 here:
[https://www3.nd.edu/~kogge/courses/cse30151-fa17/Public/other/tikz_tutorial.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ekogge/courses/cse30151-fa17/Public/other/tikz_tutorial.pdf)

and their output seems to have no eaten arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial does `\tikzset{->}` *globally*. This is why it works in the tutorial. In my opinion this is a somewhat questionable approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
This is your code fragment:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state, initial] (s1) {$s_1$};
\node[state, right=2cm of s1] (s2) {$s_2$};
\node[state, accepting, right=2cm of s2] (s3) {$s_3$};

\draw   (s1) edge[loop above] node{0} (s1)
        (s1) edge[above] node{1} (s2)
        (s2) edge[loop above] node{1} (s2)
        (s2) edge[above] node{0} (s3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

An appropriate way to get the arrow is to add \texttt{->} in a \emph{local
group}. (It gets added to the \verb|\draw| command.)
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state, initial] (s1) {$s_1$};
\node[state, right=2cm of s1] (s2) {$s_2$};
\node[state, accepting, right=2cm of s2] (s3) {$s_3$};

\draw[->]   (s1) edge[loop above] node{0} (s1)
        (s1) edge[above] node{1} (s2)
        (s2) edge[loop above] node{1} (s2)
        (s2) edge[above] node{0} (s3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

The tutorial you quote adds \verb|\tikzset{->}| \emph{globally}.
\tikzset{->}%
As you saw, this can lead to a lot of confusion, but it also adds the arrows.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state, initial] (s1) {$s_1$};
\node[state, right=2cm of s1] (s2) {$s_2$};
\node[state, accepting, right=2cm of s2] (s3) {$s_3$};

\draw   (s1) edge[loop above] node{0} (s1)
        (s1) edge[above] node{1} (s2)
        (s2) edge[loop above] node{1} (s2)
        (s2) edge[above] node{0} (s3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

If I was you I would avoid adding this globally (and perhaps select another tutorial).

\end{document}
```

[image]